# Postgres varchar type changed with index gives bad performances

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, varchar

New to Postgres, I can't understand why changing a type from varchar(255) to varchar(36) on a field **with an index** drastically decreases performances from 40ms to 5s on a huge request with joins on this field.

I tried to reindex and got same result.
If the field comes back to varchar(255) the good performances are back too!

Is-it a problem because the index on the field is joined to a field on another table that have kept varchar(255) ?

**EDIT**: added query plan (good luck...) - after changing to varchar (36)

```
Limit  (cost=548253.86..548253.88 rows=8 width=1648) (actual time=11558.810..11558.812 rows=8 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=548253.86..548302.20 rows=19337 width=1648) (actual time=11558.807..11558.808 rows=8 loops=1)
        Sort Key: usr_wines.winery
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=547238.66..547867.12 rows=19337 width=1648) (actual time=11557.853..11558.635 rows=28 loops=1)
              Group Key: usr_wines.id, shd_countries.image, shd_regions.name, shd_appellations.name, shd_categories.image, shd_categories.name_en, shd_volumes.name
              ->  Sort  (cost=547238.66..547287.01 rows=19337 width=1677) (actual time=11557.795..11557.865 rows=380 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: usr_wines.id, shd_countries.image, shd_regions.name, shd_appellations.name, shd_categories.image, shd_categories.name_en, shd_volumes.name
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 220kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=97215.88..531781.46 rows=19337 width=1677) (actual time=1400.559..11554.940 rows=380 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=97215.74..528521.66 rows=19337 width=1675) (actual time=1400.532..11552.199 rows=380 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: (usr_wines.category_id = shd_categories.id)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1900
                                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=97215.74..526780.25 rows=19337 width=651) (actual time=1400.480..11550.852 rows=380 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: ((usr_bottles.wine_id)::text = (usr_wines.id)::text)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on usr_bottles  (cost=0.00..308700.55 rows=4111092 width=74) (actual time=0.511..7610.026 rows=4384249 loops=1)
                                            Filter: ((output_type IS NULL) AND (status = 1))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 2354675
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=96206.63..96206.63 rows=11129 width=614) (actual time=1219.200..1219.200 rows=120 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 8192  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 86kB
                                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=64006.72..96206.63 rows=11129 width=614) (actual time=707.669..1218.683 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                  Hash Cond: (usr_wines.appellation_id = shd_appellations.id)
                                                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=63905.91..95978.92 rows=11129 width=599) (actual time=706.019..1216.918 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                        Hash Cond: (usr_wines.region_id = shd_regions.id)
                                                        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=63891.53..95822.44 rows=11129 width=587) (actual time=705.721..1216.489 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                              Hash Cond: (usr_wines.country_id = shd_countries.id)
                                                              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=63883.26..95667.68 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=705.346..1215.972 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                                    Hash Cond: ((usr_tastings.wine_id)::text = (usr_wines.id)::text)
                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on usr_tastings  (cost=0.00..21800.36 rows=471963 width=37) (actual time=0.343..304.762 rows=472470 loops=1)
                                                                          Filter: (status = 1)
                                                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 71559
                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=62928.14..62928.14 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=654.845..654.845 rows=74 loops=1)
                                                                          Buckets: 8192  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 79kB
                                                                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=47770.34..62928.14 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=247.452..654.581 rows=74 loops=1)
                                                                                Hash Cond: ((usr_ratings.wine_id)::text = (usr_wines.id)::text)
                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on usr_ratings  (cost=0.00..10172.90 rows=214616 width=37) (actual time=0.473..170.696 rows=214368 loops=1)
                                                                                      Filter: (status = 1)
                                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 8904
                                                                                ->  Hash  (cost=46815.23..46815.23 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=199.285..199.285 rows=57 loops=1)
                                                                                      Buckets: 8192  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 77kB
                                                                                      ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=36693.98..46815.23 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=8.331..198.889 rows=57 loops=1)
                                                                                            Hash Cond: ((usr_pairings.wine_id)::text = (usr_wines.id)::text)
                                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on usr_pairings  (cost=0.00..5899.86 rows=175239 width=37) (actual time=0.036..92.293 rows=174939 loops=1)
                                                                                                  Filter: (status = 1)
                                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 7450
                                                                                            ->  Hash  (cost=35738.87..35738.87 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=1.107..1.107 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                                                  Buckets: 8192  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 74kB
                                                                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on usr_wines  (cost=223.94..35738.87 rows=11129 width=574) (actual time=0.331..0.491 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                                                        Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1)
                                                                                                        Filter: (status = 1)
                                                                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 14
                                                                                                        Heap Blocks: exact=42
                                                                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on usr_wines_on_user_id_idx  (cost=0.00..221.16 rows=11830 width=0) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=42 loops=1)
                                                                                                              Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=5.90..5.90 rows=190 width=21) (actual time=0.195..0.195 rows=190 loops=1)
                                                                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB
                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on shd_countries  (cost=0.00..5.90 rows=190 width=21) (actual time=0.033..0.132 rows=190 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=9.17..9.17 rows=417 width=20) (actual time=0.270..0.270 rows=417 loops=1)
                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 31kB
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on shd_regions  (cost=0.00..9.17 rows=417 width=20) (actual time=0.018..0.132 rows=417 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=66.47..66.47 rows=2747 width=23) (actual time=1.599..1.599 rows=2747 loops=1)
                                                        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 190kB
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on shd_appellations  (cost=0.00..66.47 rows=2747 width=23) (actual time=0.016..0.854 rows=2747 loops=1)
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=6 width=1040) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=6 loops=380)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on shd_categories  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=1040) (actual time=0.018..0.023 rows=6 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using shd_volumes_pkey on shd_volumes  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=380)
                                Index Cond: (usr_wines.volume_id = id)
Planning time: 45.061 ms
Execution time: 11560.189 ms
```

**EDIT 2**: this morning, after reopening my MacBookPro, everything is at the same speed as yesterday before the migration !!

Look at the same EXPLAIN and the delays:

```
Limit  (cost=25254.28..25254.30 rows=8 width=1587) (actual time=16.349..16.351 rows=8 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=25254.28..25254.90 rows=247 width=1587) (actual time=16.347..16.347 rows=8 loops=1)
        Sort Key: usr_wines.winery
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=25241.31..25249.34 rows=247 width=1587) (actual time=15.156..16.153 rows=28 loops=1)
              Group Key: usr_wines.id, shd_countries.image, shd_regions.name, shd_appellations.name, shd_categories.image, shd_categories.name_en, shd_volumes.name
              ->  Sort  (cost=25241.31..25241.93 rows=247 width=1616) (actual time=15.068..15.133 rows=380 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: usr_wines.id, shd_countries.image, shd_regions.name, shd_appellations.name, shd_categories.image, shd_categories.name_en, shd_volumes.name
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 220kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.95..25231.50 rows=247 width=1616) (actual time=0.278..13.327 rows=380 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (usr_wines.volume_id = shd_volumes.id)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 13680
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.95..25092.95 rows=247 width=1614) (actual time=0.258..10.480 rows=380 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: (usr_wines.category_id = shd_categories.id)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1900
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.95..25069.64 rows=247 width=590) (actual time=0.228..9.727 rows=380 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.39..6867.48 rows=142 width=553) (actual time=0.179..4.943 rows=120 loops=1)
                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.11..6627.81 rows=142 width=538) (actual time=0.173..4.636 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.84..6549.21 rows=142 width=526) (actual time=0.166..4.333 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.69..6500.72 rows=142 width=513) (actual time=0.161..4.040 rows=120 loops=1)
                                                              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.27..3776.28 rows=142 width=513) (actual time=0.120..2.399 rows=53 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.85..2044.12 rows=142 width=513) (actual time=0.085..1.112 rows=42 loops=1)
                                                                          ->  Index Scan using usr_wines_on_user_id_idx on usr_wines  (cost=0.43..287.26 rows=142 width=513) (actual time=0.024..0.127 rows=28 loops=1)
                                                                                Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
                                                                                Filter: (status = 1)
                                                                                Rows Removed by Filter: 14
                                                                          ->  Index Scan using usr_tastings_on_wine_id_idx on usr_tastings  (cost=0.42..12.35 rows=2 width=37) (actual time=0.033..0.034 rows=1 loops=28)
                                                                                Index Cond: ((usr_wines.id)::text = (wine_id)::text)
                                                                                Filter: (status = 1)
                                                                    ->  Index Scan using usr_ratings_on_wine_id_idx on usr_ratings  (cost=0.42..12.18 rows=2 width=37) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=42)
                                                                          Index Cond: ((usr_wines.id)::text = (wine_id)::text)
                                                                          Filter: (status = 1)
                                                              ->  Index Scan using usr_pairings_on_wine_id_idx on usr_pairings  (cost=0.42..19.15 rows=4 width=37) (actual time=0.028..0.030 rows=2 loops=53)
                                                                    Index Cond: ((usr_wines.id)::text = (wine_id)::text)
                                                                    Filter: (status = 1)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using shd_countries_pkey on shd_countries  (cost=0.14..0.33 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=120)
                                                              Index Cond: (usr_wines.country_id = id)
                                                  ->  Index Scan using shd_regions_pkey on shd_regions  (cost=0.27..0.54 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=120)
                                                        Index Cond: (usr_wines.region_id = id)
                                            ->  Index Scan using shd_appellations_pkey on shd_appellations  (cost=0.28..1.68 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=120)
                                                  Index Cond: (usr_wines.appellation_id = id)
                                      ->  Index Scan using usr_bottles_on_wine_id_idx on usr_bottles  (cost=0.56..127.99 rows=19 width=74) (actual time=0.034..0.039 rows=3 loops=120)
                                            Index Cond: ((usr_wines.id)::text = (wine_id)::text)
                                            Filter: ((output_type IS NULL) AND (status = 1))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=6 width=1040) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=6 loops=380)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on shd_categories  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=1040) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=6 loops=1)
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.56 rows=37 width=18) (actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=37 loops=380)
                                ->  Seq Scan on shd_volumes  (cost=0.00..1.37 rows=37 width=18) (actual time=0.007..0.012 rows=37 loops=1)
Planning time: 29.919 ms
Execution time: 16.728 ms
```

Is-it possible that there is a kind of cache on indexes or something like that ?

**The query**:

```
SELECT usr_wines.id, usr_wines.winery, usr_wines.name, usr_wines.year, usr_wines.image_file_name, usr_wines.image2_file_name, usr_wines.image3_file_name,  usr_wines.price, usr_wines.currency,  usr_wines.maturity_from, usr_wines.maturity_to, usr_wines.apogee_from, usr_wines.apogee_to,  usr_wines.favorite, usr_wines.wishlist, usr_wines.comment, usr_wines.alcohol,  usr_wines.country_id, usr_wines.region_id, usr_wines.appellation_id, usr_wines.classification_id, usr_wines.hue_id, usr_wines.container_id, usr_wines.capsule_id,  shd_countries.image AS country_image,  shd_regions.name AS region_name,  shd_appellations.name AS appellation_name,  shd_categories.image AS category_image_name, shd_categories.name_en AS category_name,  shd_volumes.name AS volume_name,  
COUNT(DISTINCT(usr_bottles.id)) AS bottle_count  
FROM usr_wines  
LEFT JOIN usr_bottles ON usr_wines.id = usr_bottles.wine_id AND usr_bottles.status=1 AND usr_bottles.output_type IS NULL  
LEFT JOIN usr_tastings ON usr_wines.id = usr_tastings.wine_id AND usr_tastings.status=1  
LEFT JOIN usr_ratings ON usr_wines.id = usr_ratings.wine_id AND usr_ratings.status=1  
LEFT JOIN usr_pairings ON usr_wines.id = usr_pairings.wine_id AND usr_pairings.status=1  
LEFT JOIN shd_countries ON usr_wines.country_id = shd_countries.id  
LEFT JOIN shd_regions ON usr_wines.region_id = shd_regions.id  
LEFT JOIN shd_appellations ON usr_wines.appellation_id = shd_appellations.id  
LEFT JOIN shd_classifications ON usr_wines.classification_id = shd_classifications.id  
LEFT JOIN shd_categories ON usr_wines.category_id = shd_categories.id  
LEFT JOIN shd_volumes ON usr_wines.volume_id = shd_volumes.id  
WHERE usr_wines.user_id = 1 AND usr_wines.status=1  
GROUP BY usr_wines.id,  shd_countries.image,  shd_regions.name,  shd_appellations.name,  shd_categories.image, shd_categories.name_en,  shd_volumes.name  
ORDER BY usr_wines.winery asc  
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: *show the query plans*

Comment: I added it. Note that the query contains lots of LEFT JOIN but got 10 times speed with my varchar(255)...

Comment: Please show us the query and point out the column that was changed

Comment: The planner overestimated many of the rows. Did you run `analyze` on the table after you changed the column?

Comment: Query *plans*. Before and after. You're comparing something and asking why it got slower, but only showing part of the info. Not helpful.

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of this morning (EDIT 2) without changing anything... I also run ANALYZE on usr_wines but can't see logs about this operation. I added the query too in my EDIT. Looks like a cache issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to say what changed after you switched from `varchar(255)` to `varchar(36)` because you provided no `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for the former, but we can guess that the problem is related to table statistics.

At any rate, if you compare the scans on table `usr_wines`, your slow example has:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on usr_wines (cost=223.94..35738.87 rows=11129 width=574)
                                (actual time=0.331..0.491 rows=28 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1)
  Filter: (status = 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 14
  Heap Blocks: exact=42
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on usr_wines_on_user_id_idx (cost=0.00..221.16 rows=11830 width=0)
                                                (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=42 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
```

which is an overestimate by a factor of almost 400, while your fast example has:

```
Index Scan using usr_wines_on_user_id_idx on usr_wines (cost=0.43..287.26 rows=142 width=513)
                                                   (actual time=0.024..0.127 rows=28 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
  Filter: (status = 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 14
```

which is only wrong by a factor of 5.

Changing the data type will understandably remove all table statistics collected for the column, so subsequent queries will get bad query plans.

The solution is to `ANALYZE` the table manually to calculate table statistics.

In your case, an autovacuum that ran over night fixed the problem for you.